# Giving access to Sharepoint site for people outside organization?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm creating a site that will have people that work for my company using it( on the domain) and contractors who are not currently on the domain. I'm trying to figure out how to give access to the people who are not on our domain to the Sharepoint site.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a zone with Forms Based Authentication for the people not on the domain.
Look at this series on MSDN for guidance: [Forms Authentication in SharePoint Products and Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975136.aspx)

Comment: One thing to add, from a Sharepoint licensing prospective this option is the same as adding your external users to AD. But, with this option you save on AD licensing costs.

Comment: http://www.sharepointproconnections.com/TabId/149/NodeId/1924/License-to-Fill--Licensing-Windows-SharePoint-Services-for-the-Extranet-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To bring this answer up to date (2018), the features are now available in Sharepoint Online/Office365:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-external-sharing-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85