# SharePoint Office365 - how to give access to internal websites

Tags: security, sharepoint, office365

This has somewhat being answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783884/giving-access-to-sharepoint-site-for-people-outside-organization), but it's very outdated and the links given do not apply, at least the 2nd link.

We have a full license for Office 365 Sharepoint and I want to be able to create a web-part (Page-Viewer) to place an **internal hosted website** in an `iframe`.

For some reason the web-part has greyed-out the `Zone` and I cannot change it to `Left` or anything else. Why?

Is it possible to allow external users to access our Intranet and internal websites via Sharepoint and how please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another one of those, "I should have looked further", for the answer!

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off-for-sharepoint-online-6288296a-b6b7-4ea4-b4ed-c297bf833e30

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/manage-external-sharing-for-your-sharepoint-online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85

The features are there and available on Office365 to turn ON or OFF sharing of internal areas to external users. However, **it is risky**, not knowing really who's watching over the shoulders of people.